# Unlock Package challenge Error

Tags: salesforcedx

I am trying to complete the challenge for salesforce DX build your unlock package.  I have been having issues with it so please bare with me when i can explain the issue.   I created a project early last month to complete the badge..I got to this point ( see below Image)

[image]

then i tried to ask help here but whatever response i got it was not enough for me to resolve this issue..so i deleted the project...and create a new one...i cloned "dreamforce" through github as advised in the badge and stat working and making progress....Now i have reached to this point of badge (see below image)
[image]

and in CLI when i enter this command "sfdx force:package:create --name dreamhouse --description "My Package" --packagetype Unlocked --path force-app --nonamespace --targetdevhubusername DevHub"

I get this" ERROR running force:package:create:  The package name must be unique for the namespace." (see image below)
[image]

so it turns out that when i was doing the project before "dreamforce" unlocked package was installed..but now the issue i have that how do i bring that into my my SFDX Json file so it can look like as shown in the "Trailhead badge challenge page" or like i had it before (see image 1).. I am looking for guidance and i would appreciate if someone can be patient with me to help me through this challenge please.Its a very kind request!  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create the package because it's already created. To fix this problem, do this:

```
sfdx force:package:list
```

You'll get some output that shows your packages:

```
Namespace Prefix  Name              Id                  Alias  Description  Type
────────────────  ────────────────  ──────────────────  ─────  ───────────  ────────
                  dreamhouse        0Hoxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                      Unlocked
```

Open sfdx-project.json, and edit it so it has an `packageAliases` section:

```
{
   "packageDirectories": [
      {
         "path": "force-app",
         "default": true,
         "package": "Dreamhouse",
         "versionName": "ver 0.1",
         "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT"
      }
   ],
   "namespace": "",
   "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
   "sourceApiVersion": "47.0",
   "packageAliases": {
      "dreamhouse": "0Hoxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
   }
}
```

*Note: If the `sfdcLoginUrl` or `path` is different, use whatever is in your file.*

At this point, you should be able to continue with the next step with creating the unlocked package.

Comment: do i edit Sfdx project json in cli or go in the folder on my desktop and edit there?

Comment: @zsk_1 Presumably, use the one that's in your screenshot, just edit it to have a `packageAliases` (leave everything else as-is).

Comment: i posted another question yesterday..can you please kindly guide me with that